# Is this function defined on a set of rational numbers continuous?

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $A$ be the set of rational numbers in the unit interval $(0,1)$, that is, $A:=(0,1)\cap\mathbb{Q}$ and let the function $f:A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(\frac{m}{n}):=m\cdot n^2$, for each $\frac{m}{n}\in A$, where $m,n$ are relatively prime numbers. If we equip the set $A$ with the subspace topology (induced from the usual metric topology) of $\mathbb{R}$, is it true that the function $f$ is continuous? In fact, is there any point at which the function $f$ is continuous ?

I think that there is no point where the function $f$ is continuous. However I do not know how to proceed to show this possible fact. Can anybody give me a hint (or an answer if possible) ?

Comment: The LaTeX symbol you want is `\cdot`, then, not a period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, your function is nowhere continuous, and quite obviously so. Really, consider some point $m\over n$ and the function's value there; then the points $mn+1\over n^2$, $mn^2+1\over n^3$, $mn^3+1\over n^4$... will get progressively closer to it, but the function's values there will get progressively farther.